# Do skin makers with lower-rarity skins get more money?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, steam-workshop

Not sure if this goes in gamedev.SE or gaming.SE, but here goes.

Apparently users who contribute skins to the game that Valve adds will receive a small profit every time a user gets their gun.  Does this mean that since higher rarity guns will spread out far less than lower rarity guns, do the contributors who contribute lower rarity guns get more money? Or is the profit solely derived from the user unboxing the crate?

Comment: Pretty sure supply and demand would matter

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the rarity of the gun and how many people obtain it. If it is a low level gun, then a lot of people will have a chance at obtaining it, but the payout to you may not be that big.

If it is say a Restricted Rifle or better than you will get a higher payout if more people get ahold of it.

But as user1337 also stated, it is also based on Supply and Demand. A lot of people getting it means a lot of pay for you. But if not a lot of people are getting it, not a lot of pay for you, but each time you do get paid it will be higher.

*I may not be entirely correct on this, it is just what I have noticed in the time I have played CS:GO*